# When and how should I cancel network request for ListView Item in Android?

Tags: android, listview

Items in my ListView contains images that should be downloaded from the network. I start downloading process in **getView()** method of my adapter. The question is related to next issue: when I fling list to the end images appears after quite big delay. This time is taken by downloading process for all the items that appeared on the screen. I'd like to cancel network request when item goes outside the screen. Currently I do it when view is recycled:

```
if (convertView != null)
    CancelRequest(convertView.getTag);
```

But it cancel requests from very few items. So I'm wondering if someone know better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found better solution.
AbsListView has method setRecycleListener(RecyclerListener). A RecyclerListener is an interface with the only method onMovedToScrapHeap(View view). Probably it is the best place to cancel network request getting URL from views' tag.
See [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/widget/AbsListView.java#AbsListView.setRecyclerListener%28android.widget.AbsListView.RecyclerListener%29)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use this library https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

It provides you easy way to show images (it downloaded and cash it) by url in any place, includes ListView. It will solve the problem you have now.

If you wan't write your own solutions, here is a small tip:

1. In GetView start download image in **separate thread**. This way you don't need to wait while image will be downloaded.
2. While image is downloading set temporary image into listview.
3. When image will be downloaded change temporary image to downloaded one.

You can't cancel request in the middle of downloading (you can't stop the Thread when it already started to download). You can use `executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)` to run lots of thread in the same time. But again, I think there is no reason to write all this logic, just use Universal Image Loader.

Edit:

If you you use AyncTask for downloading images, you can do something like this:

```
URL url = new URL(Your url);
        URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
        conexion.connect();

        long lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
        InputStream is = url.openStream();

        File directory = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Directory/"
                        + yourImageName + "/");
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            podcastDirectory.mkdirs();
        }
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(directory + "/"
                + name + "." + extension);
        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        int count = 0;
        while ((count = is.read(data)) != -1) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
                // Stop everything if canceled. 
                is.close();
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
                return;
            }
            fos.write(data, 0, count);
        }
        is.close();
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
```

Comment: Are you sure this library can cancel requests in list properly? I tried this library and have found it can't.

Comment: It can't cancel requests, but it cashes the images on disk, so next time you don't need to wait while all images will be downloaded.It also downloads them in parallel way, so you usually will have images shown even after scrolling to the end of the list. Unfortunately you can't cancel the request in simple way, because you can't stop the Thread while it downloading something. How many images do you have and what is the size of the image? Usually Image Loader is more then enough for image downloading.

Comment: I have thousands of images more than 1mb each

Comment: Now I understand your problem, I updated my answer. You can download images the way I wrote. Then you will be able to call yourAsynctask.cancell(); to cancell the task. It will set the isCancelled to true and the thread will be cancelled while downloading. (in while loop)

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mentioned that I'm using **Volley** with some improvements made by myself. **It uses cache (memory and disk)**. There is method to cancel request but view might be reused much later then it dissapeared so it's better to cancel request when view goes outside the screen and I'm looking for any possibility to do it.

Comment: I am not familiar with Volley. I understand your problem to cancel request when convertView == null, but I don't know how to determine which request should be cancelled, if you can't know which convertView was recycled. Sorry.